# Handle Laravel 5.3 QueryException?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**Laravel 5.3**

I know what happens. In my boot function of AppServiceProvider I have code that shares data for all views:

```
 $unread_messages = count(Message::where('status', 0)->get());
    View::share('unread_messages', $unread_messages);
```

But, if there is no such a table ( after DB reset ), that throws an Exception

```
    [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'lara53.messages' doesn't
   exist (SQL: select * from `messages` where `status` = 0)

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'lara53.messages' doesn't
   exist
```

If I comment that code in the boot function it is okay, and all php artisan commands are working fine.

I have tried the following:

```
     try
      {
        $unread_messages = count(Message::where('status', 0)->get());
        View::share('unread_messages', $unread_messages);
} catch (Exception $e)
      {
         $e->getMessage();
      }
```

It throws same error. I've also tried this:

```
if (Schema::hasTable('messages')){
```

but then it shares nothing.

How do I handle this?

Comment: What is the output of `Schema::hasTable('messages')`?

Comment: no output, skips, that means there is no such table, so sharing data query lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use view composer so your query is not executed instantly when provider is loaded. Instead register view composer, and query will be executed only when view actually needs it.

Read more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers

Comment: thanks a lot, if i knew that AppServiceProvider  has such problems... i would use ComposerServiceProvider .

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good use of service providers, which are generally meant to bootstrap requirements of your app such as 3rd party packages. As you can see, placing queries to share data with views isn't efficient in a service provider because they are run on quite literally every single request (why should it need to run that query if you are just using the console?)

Instead, you should place this code into a middleware while considering if you should also take Robert Trzebiński's advice and put it in a view composer as well inside of that middleware.